# How to fix 'Add-Migration : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ContextTypeName' '

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

I have two DbContext in my project, i am trying to run EF Add-Migration pointing to a specific DbContext, but i have being encountering the below error.

```
Add-Migration Initial -ContextTypeName System.BLL.Contexts.TenantDbContext


Add-Migration : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ContextTypeName'.
At line:1 char:23
+ Add-Migration InitialCreation -ContextTypeName System.BLL.Contexts.TenantDbCo ...
+                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Add-Migration], ParameterBindingException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Add-Migration
```

I also specified the Default Project from the drop-down.

Comment: No, i meant EF6. You can create a .net core project that will target .net framework, so that i can still make use of .net framework libraries.

Comment: Well, I'm only able to find a ContextTypeName parameter in the `Enable-Migrations` command. From where did you get that?

Comment: Like i said @Camilo, i am making use of two DbContext, so i have to specify which DbContext i am adding a migration to.

Comment: So you need the `-Context` parameter.

Comment: If you have your dbcontexts on different projects select your project from dropdown menu in the same powershell window, otherwise you have to include the -project too :)

Comment: Have you installed `EntityFramework`? Or, do you used `EntityFrameworkCore`? `ContextTypeName ` is used in `Enable-Migrations`. Does `Add-Migration` work for the only one `DbContext`? Is there any specific reason you need `EntityFramework` instead of `EntityFrameworkCore`.

Comment: Try to follow [Make EF NuGet package / migrations and EF Tools work with new csproj format #231](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/231)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the parameters for EF Core, but attempting to run the command against EF 6. `Context` is not a valid parameter for `Add-Migrations` in EF6. According to multiple tutorials, the valid parameters are:

- Name
- Force
- ProjectName
- StartUpProjectName
- ConfigurationTypeName
- ConnectionStringName
- IgnoreChanges
- AppDomainBaseDirectory
- (CommonParameters: e.g., -Debug, -Verbose)

I've found a couple sites online that both document the parameters:

- https://coding.abel.nu/2012/03/ef-migrations-command-reference
- https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-based-migration-in-code-first.aspx