# Add-Migration : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Context'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

```
   Add-Migration : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Context'.
At line:1 char:15
+ Add-Migration -Context ManagementSystemContext
+               ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Add-Migration], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Add-Migration
```

I'm trying to add migration to App but I got this error despite using this command:

```
PM> Add-Migration -Context ManagementSystemContext
```

**I uninstalled EntityFrameWork.tools then reinstalled it and restarted visual studio and still the same error**

Comment: You can see more details with `-Verbose`

Comment: @Anu6is I have more than one context so I want to add migration to specific context

Comment: Add-Migration **NameOfYourMigration** -Context ManagementSystemContext

Comment: @klekmek I tried and it gave the same error

Comment: @Anu6is as you can see my question I have mentioned that I used command
 Add-Migration -Context ManagementSystemContext
and still git the error

Comment: Yes, and I added a migration name, which you omitted

Comment: @Anu6is it gives me the same error

Comment: @Anu6is it worked smoothly in my last projects, I don't know what happened

Comment: see if this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/a/32993262/11159372 ... by all means it should work though https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/providers?tabs=vs

Comment: PM> Add-Migration ManagementSystemContext

Comment: 1. Please share your project file to check if you have installed matched package: `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`, `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`. 2. Please share your `ManagementSystemContext` and check if it extends `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext`. 3. Plase share your Startup.cs about how do you register `ManagementSystemContext`.

Comment: Or you can try to use EF Core Tool.  1. Install by using: `PM>dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
`. 2. run command for migration: `PM> dotnet ef migrations add MigrationName --context ManagementSystemContext--output-dir MigrationFileLocationName --project ProjectName`.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem and I couldn't realize what it is. After 2-3 restarts of the PC and the VS, making the same command

```
Add-Migration NameOfTheMigration -Context MyContext
```

it appear something in the lines of

`"if you are using EntityFramework or EntityFrameworkCore, make sure that you type EntityFramework\Add-Migration, or EntityFrameworkCore\Add-Migration".`

I did that and the migration was on.

So the command line looked like this:

```
EntityFrameworkCore\Add-Migration NameOfTheMigration -Context MyContext
```

I'm guessing that there were both, EF and EFCore, so the PMC was confused.
Anyway, this is what worked for me.

Comment: EF6 appears to have its own prefix: "Both Entity Framework Core and Entity Framework 6 are installed. The Entity Framework Core tools are running. Use 'EntityFramework6\Add-Migration' for Entity Framework 6."

Comment: this solved it for me. weird, because I wasnt getting that warning.

Comment: I have been using EFCore 7 for an year and all of a sudden I got this error. Prefixing Migration command with `EntityFrameworkCore\\` solved the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After "Add-Migration" command EF first expects the name of the migration.
You can cheek [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/providers?tabs=vs) and [code sample](https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs/tree/main/samples/core/Schemas/TwoProjectMigrations) to see if you did something wrong.
Also you can try to do it via .net core CLI instead of Package-Manager Console, like:

```
dotnet ef migrations add MigrationName --context ManagementSystemContext --output-dir Dir
```

Hope something will help.

Comment: gives me this error :

Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
Possible reasons for this include:
  * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
  * You intended to execute a .NET program, but dotnet-ef does not exist.
  * You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.

Comment: You need to install the dotnet ef core CLI. `dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef` in cmd/powershell. Then try again.

Answer (score 0):

If your project has **two contexts** as well as **Multi Startup**. You must do the following steps:

1- First, take the project out of Multi StartUp mode and set the project startup to your desired Startup.

2. Then in the Package Manger Console section, type the following command:

   Add-Migration -Context ContextName

NOTE : Your default Project in package manger console must set as your **DataAccess class libarary**

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem when attempting to run this against EF6, but using the parameters for EF Core. `Context` is not a valid parameter for EF6. For details on the available parameters, see [my answer on this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77123881/83852).